# Sort function does not seem to break ties

Tags: haskell

I just started learning Haskell.
I'm going through the exercises of "Real World Haskell", chapter 3 and I'm stumped on a behavior I don't understand.

I don't understand why my `grahamSort` does not seem to break ties properly. The function first finds a reference point P (through `grahamGetFirstCandidate`) then sorts the other points according to the angle they and P form with the x axis. I'm using (minus) the cosine as a proxy for the angle.
`grahamGetFirstCandidate` seems to work as expected.

The code (sorry it's probably not very clean):

```
import Data.List as List

data TwoD = TwoD {
x :: Float,
y :: Float
} deriving (Show, Eq)

dotProduct :: TwoD -> TwoD -> Float
dotProduct (TwoD xa ya) (TwoD xb yb) = xa * xb + ya * yb

grahamGetFirstCandidate :: [TwoD] -> TwoD
grahamGetFirstCandidate [] = error "Trying to find point with minimum y in empty List"
grahamGetFirstCandidate (p:ps) = search p ps where
    search :: TwoD -> [TwoD] -> TwoD
    search pmin [] = pmin
    search pmin (p1:ps) | y pmin > y p1 = search p1 ps
                        | y pmin < y p1 = search pmin ps
                        | x pmin > x p1 = search p1 ps
                        | otherwise = search pmin ps

norm2 :: TwoD -> Float
norm2 (TwoD x y) = sqrt (x ** 2 + y ** 2)

minusCosAngleWithX :: TwoD -> Float
minusCosAngleWithX v = (-1) * dotProduct (TwoD 1 0) v / norm2 v

-- compare according to the angle with X axis. I did not know about Data.Ord.comparing
angleWithXCompare :: TwoD -> TwoD -> Ordering
angleWithXCompare p1 p2 | minusCosAngleWithX p1 > minusCosAngleWithX p2 = GT
                       | minusCosAngleWithX p1 < minusCosAngleWithX p2 = LT
                       | norm2 p1 > norm2 p2 = GT -- break ties
                       | norm2 p1 < norm2 p2 = LT
                       | otherwise = EQ

vectorDiff :: TwoD -> TwoD -> TwoD
vectorDiff p1 p2 = TwoD (x p2 - x p1) (y p2 - y p1)

grahamSort :: [TwoD] -> [TwoD]
-- sortBy angle (~-cosine) of (p1, p) with x axis
grahamSort ps = let p1 = grahamGetFirstCandidate ps in
                   p1 : List.sortBy (angleWithXCompare . vectorDiff p1) (filter (/=p1) ps)
main :: IO()
main = let ps = [TwoD 4 3, TwoD 5 1, TwoD 4 1, TwoD 1 2, TwoD 5 2, TwoD 2 1, TwoD 3 5, TwoD 2 3]
    in do
     print ps
     print $ grahamGetFirstCandidate ps
     print $ grahamSort ps
```

Here's the output I get

```
[TwoD {x = 4.0, y = 3.0},TwoD {x = 5.0, y = 1.0},TwoD {x = 4.0, y = 1.0},TwoD {x = 1.0, y = 2.0},TwoD {x = 5.0, y = 2.0},TwoD {x = 2.0, y = 1.0},TwoD {x = 3.0, y = 5.0},TwoD {x = 2.0, y = 3.0}]
TwoD {x = 2.0, y = 1.0} -- This is the correct result
[TwoD {x = 2.0, y = 1.0},TwoD {x = 5.0, y = 1.0},TwoD {x = 4.0, y = 1.0},TwoD {x = 5.0, y = 2.0},TwoD {x = 4.0, y = 3.0},TwoD {x = 2.0, y = 3.0},TwoD {x = 3.0, y = 5.0},TwoD {x = 1.0, y = 2.0}]
```

What I want (and was expecting) is that the point (4, 1) appears **before** (5, 1) in the sorted list.

If I change the order of the input points it swaps (4, 1) and (5, 1) in the output as well:

```
main = let ps = [TwoD 4 3, TwoD 4 1, TwoD 5 1, TwoD 1 2, TwoD 5 2, TwoD 2 1, TwoD 3 5, TwoD 2 3]
    in do
     print ps
     print $ grahamGetFirstCandidate ps
     print $ grahamSort ps

[TwoD {x = 4.0, y = 3.0},TwoD {x = 4.0, y = 1.0},TwoD {x = 5.0, y = 1.0},TwoD {x = 1.0, y = 2.0},TwoD {x = 5.0, y = 2.0},TwoD {x = 2.0, y = 1.0},TwoD {x = 3.0, y = 5.0},TwoD {x = 2.0, y = 3.0}]
TwoD {x = 2.0, y = 1.0}
[TwoD {x = 2.0, y = 1.0},TwoD {x = 4.0, y = 1.0},TwoD {x = 5.0, y = 1.0},TwoD {x = 5.0, y = 2.0},TwoD {x = 4.0, y = 3.0},TwoD {x = 2.0, y = 3.0},TwoD {x = 3.0, y = 5.0},TwoD {x = 1.0, y = 2.0}]
```

I'm obviously missing something, any help will be appreciated.

Edit: Well, I'm noticing now the order of the last points is not correct either: (3, 5) should appear before (2, 3). When I print the cosines, they look correct (=should give the right order, up to the ties), so there's probably something wrong with `angleWithXCompare`.

Comment: Completely unrelated to your problem, but you might like `angleWithXCompare p1 p2 = compare (minusCosAngleWithX p1, norm2 p1) (minusCosAngleWithX p2, norm2 p2)` or perhaps `angleWithXCompare p1 p2 = compare (minusCosAngleWithX p1) (minusCosAngleWithX p2) <> compare (norm2 p1) (norm2 p2)`. (The latter simplifies quite nicely once you learn about `comparing`: `angleWithXCompare = comparing minusCosAngleWithX <> comparing norm2`.)

Comment: Thanks @DanielWagner, that's much clearer than my 5-line boilerplate function. I don't really understand what `<>` does though (except for _the right thing_ in this usecase). Any chance there's a specific name for this symbol? It's tough to Google and Hoogle results seem irrelevant ;).

Comment: The [alpha deployment of the next version of Hoogle](http://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=%3C%3E) gets the right answer for `(<>)`. It's another name for `mappend` from `Monoid` -- and there happen to be `Monoid` instances for `Ordering` and `a -> b` (provided `b` is a `Monoid`) that do what's wanted here.

Comment: Thanks. Did not really get it for now but at least I know where to find the doc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something is not right with your "comparison" function, e.g.:

```
test =
  let p1 = TwoD {x = 2.0, y = 1.0}
      p2 = TwoD 5 1
      p3 = TwoD 4 1
      cmp = angleWithXCompare . vectorDiff p1
  in (cmp p2 p3, cmp p3 p2)
```

This yields:

```
ghci> test
(LT, LT)
```

I would expect either `(LT,GT)` or `(GT,LT)`

Update: You want to use this comparison function:

```
  cmp a b = angleWithXCompare (vectorDiff p1 a) (vectorDiff p1 b)
```

in your `List.sortBy` call, e.g.:

```
grahamSort ps =
 let p1 = grahamGetFirstCandidate ps
 in
    p1 : List.sortBy cmp (filter (/=p1) ps)
 where cmp a b = angleWithXCompare (vectorDiff p1 a) (vectorDiff p1 b)
```

Comment: Thanks! I got carried away with the `.` and partial function application... What I wanted to have was (vectorDiff p1) applied to all the arguments before they were passed to `angleWithXCompare`. I think what was happening instead is that my function was passing the first argument to `(vectorDiff p1)` but the second one straight to `angleWithXCompare`.